# @popperjs error TS2344: Type 'Options' does not satisfy the constraint 'Obj'

Tags: angular, angular15

After upgrading my application to angular 15 I see these errors while trying to build it. It does not have any trace where it start and what is the issue. I did not use `popperjs` in my application, may be some deep dependencies are using it

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a problem with `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` as I was using an older version of the it. So I updated all my other dependencies to latest and install them and build again and it resolved the issues